# Accessing jenkins remote api from javascript without JSONP

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jsonp, remote-access

I have a javascript application which displays information about jenkins jobs. Till recently I used an ajax call with JSONP to retreive data from jenkins (jenkins and client are on different servers), but in latest jenkins releases JSONP api is disabled.

I read [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) page on jenkins wiki, but still I don't know how to do it from javascript. I tried to use basic http authentication (jenkins uses https) with no luck. I also tried to use the crumbissuer, but in the logs jenkins says that crumb is invalid...

How can I use jenkins remote api from javascript? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I tried http authentication like this (I do not have the exact code anymore):

```
$.ajax({
        dataType : "json",
        url : jenkinsURL + "/job/" + jenkinsJob + "/api/json?tree=name,url,color",
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password);
        }
       })
    .done(function(data) {
        // process data
    })
```

I tried to use crumb issuer similarly:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType : "json",
        url : jenkinsURL + "/job/" + jenkinsJob + "/api/json?tree=name,url,color",
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(".crumb", "<received crumb>");
        }
       })
    .done(function(data) {
        // process data
    })
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Hi, I added some sample code to my original post...

Answer (score 0):

Setting Request headers with these worked for me in Java.

```
URL url = new URL(JenkinsURL);
HttpURLConnection xhr= (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();


xhr.setRequestMethod("GET");
xhr.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20130401 Firefox/31.0");
xhr.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
xhr.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password);          
xhr.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
xhr.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
xhr.setDoOutput(true);

xhr.connect();


System.out.println(xhr.getResponseCode());// Hack to run the request if it wasnt run
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(xhr.getInputStream()));
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //some code
    }
```